# Ubuntu 12.04 Fails to Boot after Reboot

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, dell, reboot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on several Dell c6220 servers. The install was successful and all hardware is recognized.

The problem that I am running into is that when issuing the `reboot` command or when pressing `ctrl-alt-del`, the server shuts down, but never comes back up. Instead, the fan revs up to full speed and stays that way until I power the server down.

Once the server has been powered down via the power button, Ubuntu will boot just fine -- until the next reboot.

I have found that by rebooting the server via the DRAC web interface will reboot the server correctly.

I have also found that this problem does not exist with CentOS -- I can press `ctrl-alt-del` all day long and it always comes back up.

I've tried several kernel parameters such as:

```
reboot=bios
reboot=pci
reboot=acpi
reboot=cold
acpi=off
noapic
```

Nothing seems to work.

I have also tried upgrading to kernel `3.4`, but no change there, either.

Has anyone run into a similar problem or any pointers on troubleshooting?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the kernel option `nolapic` solves this issue. Whether or not disabling lapic is safe is something I still need to look into.